# Typo3: How to insert the Page Title into a BE Content Element using Automaketemplate

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Using automaketemplate (not templavoila), the following works fine in typo3 4.5.2 and displays "This is the the current page title... Whatever the page title is" :

First place the following ts in an extension template:

```
page.10.subparts.pageTitle = TEXT
page.10.subparts.pageTitle.field = title
page.10.subparts.pageTitle.field.debugData = 1
```

Next, enter the following in a header content element in the BE: 
 This is the current page title... {page:title}

However, when updating to version 4.5.24 , the page title no longer replaces {page:title} and just displays "This is the current page title: {page:title} "

Perhaps there is a better way to do the above? Something that will work in 4.5.24 + ? I have followed all the upgrade procedures but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware, don't use debug stuff in Production.
The field names in curly brackets are for use in Typoscript, not in the BE, together with insertData.
As such, for example:

```
page.10.subparts.pageTitle = TEXT
page.10.subparts.pageTitle.value = <h1>{page:title}</h1> 
page.10.subparts.pageTitle.insertData = 1
```

If you want to combine, say a content element's title with the page title, do this in the TS template.

For use with css_styled_content (Have a look at /typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/static/setup.txt, you can override everything from here), I would try overriding this:

```
lib.stdheader.10.2.dataWrap = <h2{register:headerStyle}{register:headerClass}>|</h2>
```

by this:

```
lib.stdheader.10.2.dataWrap = <h2{register:headerStyle}{register:headerClass}> - {page:title}|</h2>
```

as we're already using dataWrap, it should be sufficient!

Comment: Thank you Urs. Excuse the 'spoon-feeding' request: What exactly would all the Typoscript look like in order to combine the Page Title with the content elements title? (to append the Page Title to the content element title)

Comment: It depends on how you render the content. If you use css_styled_content, there is lib.stdheader - If you modify that property with typoscript, you can modify the way headers are rendered. Untested: lib.stdheader.2.append.value = - {page:title} and lib.stdheader.2.append.insertData = 1 might modify all h2 headers. More on http://www.typo3lexikon.de/typo3-tutorials/extensions/css-styled-content/libstdheader.html?L=0 (in German)

Comment: Urs - Thanks for lib.stdheader - Pls add this to your answer in nice format so I can tick thanks to you.
This works:
(from http://www.typo3-addict.com/2010/03/a-custom-header-layout/)

lib.stdheader.10.5 = COA
lib.stdheader.10.5 {

10 < lib.stdheader.10.1
10.fontTag = <h2{register:headerStyle}{register:headerClass}>|

# Second object: The page title to be appended.
20 = TEXT
20.value = &nbsp; {page:title}
20.insertData = 1

# Third object: Closing the H2 tag which we opened
# in the first object.
30 = TEXT
30.value = </h2>
}

Comment: Beware again! The fonttag setting has been retired from css_styled_content a long time ago, see http://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3_4.3.12#Upgrading - see modified answer above.

Comment: lib.stdheader.10.2.dataWrap = <h2{register:headerStyle}{register:headerClass}> - {page:title}|</h2> is so much better. Works perfectly. The code that I'd suggested caused other issues as well like not allowing h1 to be appended. Thank you very much. The 'Bewares' thankfully noted!